# alternate text with a special number

Tags: php

I am using this code to add one alt text to all website images

```
if (stristr($navigator_user_agent, "msie")) { 
  return '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $link . '" alt="crafts" style="width: expression(this.width > 501 ? 500 : true);" /></a>'; 
} 
else { 
  return '<img src="' . $link . '" title="ward2u fourm arts" alt="ward2u - 1" style="max-width: 500px;" /></a>'; 
} /* End Image RESIZE */

    }
```

How can I add the same text with numbers from 1 to 20?
If the page has 20 pictures
Each image has alternate text with a special number, as in the following example:

alt="ward2u - 1"

alt="ward2u - 2"

alt="ward2u - 3"

Comment: Do you have a loop around this code that you're not showing?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question
Generally the code is an extract from File class_bbcode
It gives one alt description for all pictures
I want to give a unique alt description to every picture on one page

Comment: Why question is more about how you are getting 20 images on the page. Is it looping through number 1 through 20 somewhere? What is class_bbcode? A file from vbulletin?

Comment: Hello my friend
My site specializes in plastic arts
So it is important to display pictures of artists' paintings
On each page we show 20 plates

https://www.ward2u.com/showthread.php?t=16465&page=2

If you are a computer user
The mouse hovering over the image reads the description of the images
Repetitive image description is bad for SEO
As for the aforementioned file, it is specific to Violetin 3.8.11
You're always welcome